# Kurento webRTC streaming server - Chrome issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, kurento

I installed a Kurento server on centos and Node.js. I'm facing some problems with streaming with Chrome browser, console reports the following error:

> NavigatorUserMediaError
>       constraintName: ""
>       message: "Only secure origins are allowed (see: https://goo.gl/Y0ZkNV)."
>       name: "PermissionDeniedError"

the error is caught int that method:

```
function log(console, level) {
  var items = this

  var item = document.createElement('li');

  var argv = [].slice.call(arguments, 2)

  // initialise the item
  item.innerHTML = argv.map(renderData).join(' ');

  // add the class
  item.classList.add(level);

  // add to the list
  items.appendChild(item);

  setTimeout(function() {
    items.parentNode.scrollTop = items.offsetHeight;
  }, 100);

  // pass the call through to the original window console
  console[level].apply(console, argv);
};
```

Someone can help me to solve?

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, seems like your Kurento server is not configured to work on HTTPS:

> Starting with Chrome 47, WebRTC is only allowed from SECURE ORIGINS
>   (HTTPS or localhost).

Follow their [guide](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/latest/mastering/securing-kurento-applications.html) to make Kurento work on HTTPS protocol.